# Laravel 5 - Namespace + Dynamic Model

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a very basic function to delete stuff on a simple website on Laravel 4.x that works like this:

```
public function delete()
{
    ...
    $Model = Input::get('Model');       
    $Action = $Model::find($Id);
   ...
}
```

Now on Laravel 5, I'm trying to do the same but so far I can't because the namespaces. Since the $Model is dynamic I don't want to make `use` for everything.

And something like this:

```
use App\C\Models as Model;

public function delete()
{
...
$Action = Model\$Model::find($Id);
...
}
```

Simple do not works. What'd be the right approach to get this to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply store the namespaced classname as a string first:

```
$Model = Input::get('Model');
$NamespacedModel = '\\Model\\' . $Model;
$Action = $NamespacedModel::find($Id);
```

Comment: i have been try like code in your comment, 
but i have error 
syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Comment: @VinraGunantaPandia Maybe your PHP version is too old? I believe this was added in PHP 5.3

Comment: not because that, 
i must named variable with $class, 


$class = '\\Model\\' . $Model;
$Action = $class::find($Id);

and now its work

Answer (score 2):

In the same case, My code is like this...

```
public function FunctionName(Request $request)
{
    $modelName = $request->model;

    $model = '\\App\\Models\\'.$modelName;

    $q = $model::find($request->id);

    $q->someColumn = 'someValue';

    $q->save();

    return back();
}
```

Note: I am using Laravel 8